# How do i pass the user username and password from the login form to the server

Tags: ionic4

I have a login page with two inputs for username and password and a login button. i want to take the user's info and pass it to the user for verification and get the user details from the server.

i have tried using two approaches but none are working.

```
        <ion-list>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Username" 
         id="user">
        </ion-input>
       <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="password" 
        id="password">
       </ion-input>
       <ion-button (click)="login()">
        LogIn
     </ion-button>
     </ion-list>
```

Comment: public username:any;
  public password:any;

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) 
  {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login()
  {  
 
    this.http.get('http://test.vazy.co.ke/api-login?usertype=4&username=this.username&password=this.password').subscribe((data:any[])=>
    {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

u can create one object first
home.ts

```
register:any={};
  
onsubmit(data){

console.log(data)

}
```

home.html

```
   <ion-list>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="register.username" placeholder="Username" 
     id="user">
    </ion-input>
   <ion-input [(ngModel)]="register.password" placeholder="password" 
    id="password">
   </ion-input>
   <ion-button (click)="onsubmit(register)">
    
 </ion-button>
 </ion-list>
```

Comment: console.log(data)--->u get answer

Comment: thankyou. how do i feed this to an http get method?

Comment: or do i have to use the post method to submit the logininfo?

Comment: i think maybe use  post method because post method is most secure ,get method use pass data in ur url bar,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for this, or perhaps [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)?

You need to have a service on the other end that you can send the credentials data to.

It sounds like you are just starting out so it's probably wise to use an established login system, rather than trying to roll your own. There are a lot of edge cases, and you could easily introduce security issues by doing it on your own.

Plus these systems come with getting started guides that can walk you through the process.